# Can you tell what price an iOS user paid for an app or IAP?

Tags: ios, storekit

You can use an SKPRoductRequest to get prices for products, and you can use the App Store receipt API to get what products a user has purchased (as of iOS7).

However, I think the SKProductRequest reflects the current price for the products.

Is there any way to tell what price the user actually paid for an in-app purchase, given there might have been a price change? How about for the app itself?

Comment: You just served a joke in a plate for all those Apple hating Android fans in here. Just wanted to be the first to note this :P

Comment: @lascort what joke is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to store the purchase price on the device or server, or in your analytics package

Comment: Do you know if this is still the case?